# Parse error: Syntax error - in settings.php on line 1

Tags: php, drupal-7

I edited settings.php, adding a few lines of code at the end of settings.php, as instructed by the CloudFlare Drupal module page.

The result was that the site is down and I get this error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/intersub/public_html/drupal/sites/default/settings.php on line 1

Settings.php has all its code on one line. I used notepad++ instead of notepad, thinking this would avoid errors in line breaks encoding, which is exactly what seems to have happened.

I added missing line breaks as best I could, but i don't know programming and missed many I'm sure, especially in the coding lines (vs documenting lines).

Could someone help in pointing the missing line breaks, and possibly the line breaks I added mistakenly?

Thank you so much !!!

Jean-François

```
<?php// $Id: settings.php,v 1.39.2.3 2007/07/09 04:28:12 drumm Exp $

/**
* @file 
* Drupal site-specific configuration file. 
* 
* IMPORTANT NOTE: 
* This file may have been set to read-only by the Drupal installation 
* program. If you make changes to this file, be sure to protect it again 
* after making your modifications. Failure to remove write permissions 
* to this file is a security risk. 
* 
* The configuration file to be loaded is based upon the rules below. 
* 
* The configuration directory will be discovered by stripping the 
* website's hostname from left to right and pathname from right to 
* left. The first configuration file found will be used and any 
* others will be ignored. If no other configuration file is found 
* then the default configuration file at 'sites/default' will be used. 
* 
* For example, for a fictitious site installed at 
* http://www.drupal.org/mysite/test/, the 'settings.php' 
* is searched in the following directories: 
* 
*  1. sites/www.drupal.org.mysite.test 
*  2. sites/drupal.org.mysite.test 
*  3. sites/org.mysite.test 
*  4. sites/www.drupal.org.mysite 
*  5. sites/drupal.org.mysite 
*  6. sites/org.mysite 
*  7. sites/www.drupal.org 
*  8. sites/drupal.org 
*  9. sites/org 
* 10. sites/default 
* 
* If you are installing on a non-standard port number, prefix the 
* hostname with that number. For example, 
* http://www.drupal.org:8080/mysite/test/ could be loaded from 
* sites/8080.www.drupal.org.mysite.test/. 
*/

$update_free_access = FALSE;

/** 
* Database settings: 
* 
* Note that the $db_url variable gets parsed using PHP's built-in 
* URL parser (i.e. using the "parse_url()" function) so make sure 
* not to confuse the parser. If your username, password 
* or database name contain characters used to delineate 
* $db_url parts, you can escape them via URI hex encodings: 
* 
*   : = %3a   / = %2f   @ = %40 
*   + = %2b   ( = %28   ) = %29 
*   ? = %3f   = = %3d   & = %26 
* 
* To specify multiple connections to be used in your site (i.e. for 
* complex custom modules) you can also specify an associative array 
* of $db_url variables with the 'default' element used until otherwise 
* requested. 
* 
* You can optionally set prefixes for some or all database table names 
* by using the $db_prefix setting. If a prefix is specified, the table 
* name will be prepended with its value. Be sure to use valid database 
* characters only, usually alphanumeric and underscore. If no prefixes 
* are desired, leave it as an empty string ''. 
* 
* To have all database names prefixed, set $db_prefix as a string: 
* 
*   $db_prefix = 'main_'; 
* 
* To provide prefixes for specific tables, set $db_prefix as an array. 
* The array's keys are the table names and the values are the prefixes. 
* The 'default' element holds the prefix for any tables not specified 
* elsewhere in the array. Example: 
* 
*   $db_prefix = array( 
*     'default'   => 'main_', 
*     'users'     => 'shared_', 
*     'sessions'  => 'shared_', 
*     'role'      => 'shared_', 
*     'authmap'   => 'shared_', 
*     'sequences' => 'shared_', 
*   ); 
* 
* Database URL format: 
*   $db_url = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename'; 
*   $db_url = 'mysqli://username:password@localhost/databasename'; 
*   $db_url = 'pgsql://username:password@localhost/databasename'; 
*/

$db_url = 'mysql://intersub_drpl1:xxxxxxxxxx@localhost/intersub_drpl1';
$db_prefix = '';

/** 
* Base URL (optional). 
* 
* If you are experiencing issues with different site domains, 
* uncomment the Base URL statement below (remove the leading hash sign) 
* and fill in the URL to your Drupal installation. 
* 
* You might also want to force users to use a given domain. 
* See the .htaccess file for more information. 
* 
* Examples: 
*   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com'; 
*   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com:8888'; 
*   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com/drupal'; 
*   $base_url = 'https://www.example.com:8888/drupal'; 
* 
* It is not allowed to have a trailing slash; Drupal will add it 
* for you. 
*/

$base_url = 'http://intersubjectivite.com/drupal';
  // NO trailing slash!// 
$base_url = 'http://74.54.126.35/drupal';
  // NO trailing slash!

/** 
* PHP settings: 
* 
* To see what PHP settings are possible, including whether they can be set at 
* runtime (by using ini_set()), read the PHP documentation: 
* http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php 
* See drupal_initialize_variables() in includes/bootstrap.inc for required 
* runtime settings and the .htaccess file for non-runtime settings. Settings 
* defined there should not be duplicated here so as to avoid conflict issues. 
*/

/** 
* Some distributions of Linux (most notably Debian) ship their PHP 
* installations with garbage collection (gc) disabled. Since Drupal depends on 
* PHP's garbage collection for clearing sessions, ensure that garbage 
* collection occurs by using the most common settings. 
*/

ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);

/** 
* Set session lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the user's last visit 
* to the active session may be deleted by the session garbage collector. When 
* a session is deleted, authenticated users are logged out, and the contents 
* of the user's $_SESSION variable is discarded. 
*/

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);

/** 
* Set session cookie lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the session is 
* created to the cookie expires, i.e. when the browser is expected to discard 
* the cookie. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed". 
*/

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);

/** 
* Drupal automatically generates a unique session cookie name for each site 
* based on on its full domain name. If you have multiple domains pointing at 
* the same Drupal site, you can either redirect them all to a single domain 
* (see comment in .htaccess), or uncomment the line below and specify their 
* shared base domain. Doing so assures that users remain logged in as they 
* cross between your various domains. 
*/

# $cookie_domain = 'example.com';

/** 
* Variable overrides: 
* 
* To override specific entries in the 'variable' table for this site, 
* set them here. You usually don't need to use this feature. This is 
* useful in a configuration file for a vhost or directory, rather than 
* the default settings.php. Any configuration setting from the 'variable' 
* table can be given a new value. 
* 
* Remove the leading hash signs to enable. 
*/

# $conf = array(
#   'site_name' => 'My Drupal site',
#   'theme_default' => 'minnelli',
#   'anonymous' => 'Visitor',
# );$databases = array (  'default' =>   array (    'default' =>     array (      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'intersub_drpl1',
      'username' => 'intersub_drpl1',
      'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      ),
      ),
      );$drupal_hash_salt = 'VqW77S9adJsoMSn-4m-puXWYSXhEppaJZZ389eKuUqE';

/** 
* Code ajouté le 21-07-2015 avec l'installation du module CloudFlare 
* servant à indiquer l'adresse IP du visiteur plutôt que celle de CloudFlare 
* c.f. page du module Drupal : CloudFlare - Free Reverse Proxy, Firewall, and Global CDN 
* https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudflare 
*/

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
}
```

Comment: Linebreaks is the right idea. If you've saved it with just *carriage returns* instead of real newlines, that would usually explain the "unexpected $end in **line 1**".

Comment: Use an IDE with good syntax highlighting. To me, the problem looks like it is here `# );$databases = array (  'default' =>   array (    'default' =>     array (      'driver' => 'mysql',`  You have commented the beginning of your `$databases` array definition.

Comment: Thank you so much Mario and Mike, fortunately my hosting provider was able to restore a correct copy of the file :-)